# Trying to update livetile from backgroundaudiotask in Windows Phone 8.1: "The application identifier provided is invalid"

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, live-tile

I have a music player and would like to update the livetile with the albumart of the playing track. So each time the track changes I call a method in a seperate Windows Runtine Component. The method looks like this:

```
public async void CreateLivetile(string albumart, string artist, string trackname)
{
    try
    {
        // constants
        string textElementName = "text";
        string imageElementName = "image";

        // Create a tile update manager
        var updater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
        updater.EnableNotificationQueue(true);
        updater.Clear();

        // wide 310x150
        var tileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWide310x150PeekImage03);
        tileXml.GetElementsByTagName(textElementName).LastOrDefault().InnerText = string.Format(artist + " - " + trackname);
        var image = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName(imageElementName).FirstOrDefault();
        if (image != null)
        {
            var src = tileXml.CreateAttribute("src");
            src.Value = albumart;
            image.Attributes.SetNamedItem(src);
        }

        // square 150x150
        var squaredTileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquare150x150PeekImageAndText01);
        squaredTileXml.GetElementsByTagName(textElementName).FirstOrDefault().InnerText = string.Format(artist + " - " + trackname);
        image = squaredTileXml.GetElementsByTagName(imageElementName).LastOrDefault();
        if (image != null)
        {
            var src = squaredTileXml.CreateAttribute("src");
            src.Value = albumart;
            image.Attributes.SetNamedItem(src);
        }

        updater.Update(new TileNotification(tileXml));
        updater.Update(new TileNotification(squaredTileXml));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        // Inform the system that the task is finished.
        //_deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

When the method reaches this line:

```
var updater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
```

I get this error:

```
The application identifier provided is invalid.
```

This method does work fine in the app (front-end)...

Comment: Hello! Did you solve this problem? I have the same exception... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125246/update-livetile-from-background-task-wp8-1

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution :/

Comment: Please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125246/update-livetile-from-background-task-wp8-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is solution:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/83498107-fe0d-4a8b-93f3-02d484983953/tileupdatemanager-throws-exception?forum=wpdevelop

Just provide ID directly: 
    TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication("App")

Answer (score 2):

You've found a common bug in the simulator.

From [one of Microsoft's blogs](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/buildingapps/archive/2014/05/23/understanding-and-resolving-failures-in-windows-store-apps.aspx):

> We’ve found two scenarios that cause this failure. The first is during
>   app development when running the app in the simulator in Visual
>   Studio. This error may be thrown when updating tiles. The
>   recommendation is to run the app under the Local Machine setting
>   [...].
>
> Secondly, this failure can occur when the underlying notification
>   platform is not available on the user’s machine. If the notification
>   platform has encountered an issue that caused it to terminate, it
>   causes tile notification and updating to fail as well. The call to
>   `TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication` normally retrieves
>   the package full name, creates a notification endpoint, and performs
>   package and app name validation for the notification subsystem.
>   Problems with either of the last two steps can cause “The application
>   identifier provided is invalid” to be returned, generating this
>   exception.

See also:

- [updating tiles in Win 8 Metro app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311832/updating-tiles-in-win-8-metro-app)
- [Why is identifier for secondary tile invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433896/why-is-identifier-for-secondary-tile-invalid)
- ["cant-update-secondary-tile"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-US/bb9bd798-cafe-4492-bd2a-eae67ec83737/cant-update-secondary-tile)

Comment: I forgot to mention it is a Windows Phone 8.1 app. It also doesn't work when I'm not debugging :/.

Comment: @PhilippeMaes - Could you clarify "This method does work fine in the app (front-end)..." ?

Comment: When placing the method in my main app. So not in any background task or extra project.

Comment: This error appears while debugging on a device, too, fyi.  Not just relegated to the simulator.  You must provide the name of your Application.Current instance for it to go away - "App" usually.