# Update LiveTile from Background Task WP8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, live-tile, background-task

I cannot update manually pinned tile from Background Task.

```
var updater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
updater.EnableNotificationQueue(true);
updater.Clear();

XmlDocument tileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWideText03);

var title = "Test text";
string titleText = title == null ? String.Empty : title;
tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("text")[0].InnerText = titleText;

updater.Update(new TileNotification(tileXml));
```

Exception fires on CreateTileUpdaterForApplication(); with message: The application identifier provided is invalid.

I heard what this problem occurs on Windows Phone with 8.1 update, but I not found any solutions... Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having exactly the same issue. After three hours of research (damn waste of time :/) I found the solution:

```
var updater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication("App");
```

Thanks to the guy who posted that (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/83498107-fe0d-4a8b-93f3-02d484983953/tileupdatemanager-throws-exception?forum=wpdevelop)!
Cannot believe that I did not see the "(+1 overload(s))" when hovering the mouse over the call -.-

Comment: That did not change anything at first, then I manually uninstalled then redeployed my debug package and it worked. Thanks.